# Polars get unique values from List[Any]

Tags: python, python-polars

I want to get a list of unique values from a column of list[str],

```
import polars as pl

data = [
    {"name": "foo", "tags": ["A", "B"]},
    {"name": "bar", "tags": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"name": "baz", "tags": ["A"]},
    {"name": "bing", "tags": ["B"]},
]
df = pl.from_dicts(data)
```

Expected output: `["A", "B", "C"]`

Comment: Do you mean from the result of a `.select()` ? e.g. `df.select(pl.col("tags").flatten().unique().implode())`

Comment: `df.select(pl.col("tags").arr.explode()).unique()` this will work

Answer (score 0):

You can get the unique values to a list by,

```
tags = df["business_types"].arr.explode().unique().to_list()
>>> ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you out:

```
import polars as pl
data = [
    {"name": "foo", "tags": ["A", "B"]},
    {"name": "bar", "tags": ["A", "B", "C"]},
    {"name": "baz", "tags": ["A"]},
    {"name": "bing", "tags": ["B"]},
]
df = pl.from_dicts(data)
unique_tags = df["tags"].explode().unique()
print(unique_tags)
```

Comment: This will work, however it will throw a Deprecation warning in the latest version, you can do `df["tags"].arr.explode().unique()` instead.